# What does noexcept exactly encompass for constructors?

Tags: c++, c++11, constructor, language-lawyer, noexcept

**According to the C++ standard, what exactly does a `noexcept` *noexcept-specification* on a class constructor apply to?**

1. the *function-body*?

   1. initialization of members in the optional *ctor-initializer*?

      1. initialization of base classes in the optional *mem-initializer*s?
      2. initialization of class members in the optional *mem-initializer*s?
   2. the *compound-statement*?
   3. the *function-try-block*?
2. initialization of object base classes not initialized in the *ctor-initializer*?
3. initialization of object class members not initialized in the *ctor-initializer*?
4. something additional?

In other words, which of the above are encompassed by the `noexcept` *noexcept-specification* (i.e. trigger `std::terminate()` when throwing an exception if `noexcept(true)`)?

Please provide references to the standard. Tips on any caveats using `noexcept` for constructors are also welcome. Thanks!

Comment: I'm not a language lawyer, but the way I read it is; if anything the ctor does (including the ctors of objects it initializes) throws an exception; then it is not `noexcept`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> In other words, which of the above are encompassed by the `noexcept` *noexcept-specification*...?

The exception specification (`noexcept` and dynamic exception specification) pertains to the construction of the base classes, construction and initialisation of the members, and the code in the body of the constructor. *Basically, all functions executed in the construction of the object* - this makes sense in that the exception specification is tied to the constructor of the object, hence it should cover code executed during the construction of the object; it would be counterintuitive if any part of the construction was not covered by this.

Supporting standard quotes...

**What if an exception is thrown during construction (and possibly not handled)?**

[[except.spec]/9](http://eel.is/c++draft/except#except.spec-9)

> Whenever an exception of type `E` is thrown and the search for a handler ([except.handle]) encounters the outermost block of a function with an exception specification that does not allow `E`, then,
>
> - if the function definition has a dynamic-exception-specification, the function `std::unexpected()` is called ([except.unexpected]),
> - otherwise, the function `std::terminate()` is called ([except.terminate]).

*What does the "outermost block of a function" mean?* The body of the function.<sup>1</sup>

The [*exception specification*](http://eel.is/c++draft/except.spec#exception-specification) above includes the *noexcept-specification*.

**How is the implicitly declared exception specification determined on an implicitly declared constructor?**

[[except.spec]/15](http://eel.is/c++draft/except#except.spec-15)

> An implicitly-declared special member function `f` of some class `X` is considered to have an implicit exception specification that consists of all the members from the following sets:
>
> - if `f` is a constructor,
>
>   - the sets of potential exceptions of the constructor invocations
>
>     - for `X`'s non-variant non-static data members,
>     - for `X`'s direct base classes, and
>     - if `X` is non-abstract ([class.abstract]), for `X`'s virtual base classes,
>
>       (including default argument expressions used in such invocations) as selected by overload resolution for the implicit definition of f ([class.ctor])...
>   - the sets of potential exceptions of the initialization of non-static data members from *brace-or-equal-initializers* that are not ignored ([class.base.init]);

This provides very useful clarification on what the compiler would use to determine (and hence consider covered by) the exception specification.

---

<sup>1</sup>*What does the "outermost block of a function" mean?* There was a comment on the concern to the definition of the block of a function. The standard has no formal definition of the *block of a function*. The phrase *block of a function* is only used in the [Exception Handling [except]](http://eel.is/c++draft/#except). The phrase was included in the standard from as far back as C++98.

For further clarity on this, we would need seek alternative source and draw some reasonable conclusions.

From [Stroustrup C++ glossary](http://www.stroustrup.com/glossary.html#Gfunction-body);

> **function body** - the outermost block of a function. See also: try-block, function definition. TC++PL 2.7, 13.

And from [[dcl.fct.def.general]/1](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.fct.def.general#1) the grammar for the *function-body* that covers the *ctor-initializer* with *compound-statement* and the *function-try-block*;

> Function definitions have the form;
>
> ...
>
> *function-body*:
>       *ctor-initializer*<sub>opt</sub> *compound-statement*
>       *function-try-block*
>
> ...
>
> Any informal reference to the body of a function should be interpreted as a reference to the non-terminal *function-body*...

It is also important to bear in mind that exception specifications are associated with functions and not general blocks of code (scoped blocks etc.).

Given the age of the phrase in the exception handling clause and the Stroustrup FAQ, the *block of a function* is the same as the *function-body*, the standard could probably do with an update of the language used in the exception clause.

---

Some empirical evidence, given the code below, for the construction of `a1`, `a2` and `a3` (when the others are commented out), result in `std::terminate` being called. The result is applicable for [g++, clang](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b0a58ce594bd6d37) and [MSVC](http://rextester.com/MVFU30714).

```
struct Thrower { Thrower() { std::cout << "throwing..." << std::endl; throw 42; } };

struct AsMember { Thrower t_; AsMember() noexcept : t_{} { std::cout << "ctor" << std::endl; } };

struct AsBase : Thrower { AsBase() noexcept { std::cout << "ctor" << std::endl; } };

struct AsNSDMI { Thrower t_ {}; AsNSDMI() noexcept { std::cout << "ctor" << std::endl; } };

int main()
{
    std::set_terminate([](){ std::cout << "terminating..." << std::endl; });
    try {
        //AsMember a1{};
        //AsBase a2{};
        AsNSDMI a3{};
    }
    catch (...) { std::cout << "caught..." << std::endl; }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can probably answer this question yourself if you consider a `noexcept` constructor whose definition is not available in the current translation unit (e.g. the constructor imlementation resides in a shared library).

If `noexcept` did not apply to the entire constructor, an exception could still be emitted by the constructor somehow, defeating the purpose of `noexcept`.

The only way `noexcept` can work correctly in this scenario is if it applies to the entire constructor, including base class and member initialization.